# Trouble comparing each line in excel with python

Tags: python, excel, loops, for-loop, comparison

[image]I am trying to separate two trips which I have in excel file.
Basically if the Trip #, Invoice # and Vendor are different values for each trip where as Ticket number is same for both the trips.

I tried to open the file and loop it through each line but I am getting an key error

Below is the code I have tried so far.

```py
fileData=pd.read_excel(self.inputDir+"\\"+name,
                       dtype={'Invoice#':str,
                              'Ticket#':str,
                              'Agent1':str,
                              'Agent2':str,
                              'Commission':float,
                              'Vat Comm':float})
for i in fileData.index:
    TicketNumber = fileData['Ticket #'][i]
    print(TicketNumber)                        
    VendorNumber = fileData['Vendor'][i]
    print(VendorNumber) 
    TripID = fileData['Trip #'][i]
    print(TripID)
    i+1

    if fileData['Trip #'][i] != fileData['Trip #'][i+1] \
            and fileData['Invoice#'][i] != fileData['Invoice#'][i+1] \
            and fileData['Vendor'][i] != fileData['Vendor'][i+1] \
            and fileData['Ticket #'][i] == fileData['Ticket #'][i+1]:
        print('found different trip' ,fileData\['Trip #'\]\[i+1\])
    else:
        print('no matching record')][1]][1]
```

Comment: (1) In the code I see 'Ticket #' and 'Ticket#' (with/without space). Such differences can be a reason for a key error. (2) The line `i+1` does nothing.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Ticket # is correct I double checked it. may be its i+1 is causing error. My question is how do I compare two row values to determine difference?

Comment: I thought your problem was a key error? The error message should tell which key is missing.